# Windows Search - List Indexed Locations by Number of Items?

Tags: windows, windows-search

Beyond looking them up manually, is there any way to get the number of files in each folder that Windows search is indexing? I've noticed that the searching in Windows 7 is a tad slower that I would like it to be. I've tried to limit the search locations to the bare essentials but it still says it has over 30k files indexed, so I'm guessing there's still some low-hanging fruit that I can get rid of.

Comment: You probably spend more time tweaking it than you actually use using it. Try learning the different filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question. A way to do this is to get [esedbviewer](http://www.woanware.co.uk/?page_id=89), open the index file, export the contents to CSV, and then get the count of items for each location by opening the CSV in Excel and creating a pivot table.